# c# sharp proejct .net 4.5 dependency, should interact with a azure message queue

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I am currently working on a project that depends on .net 4.5, which I am why forced to use Microsoft.Servicebus - and thus message factory

Creating a messagefactory object, doesn't seem to be problem, but creating the message sender seem to be the issue here.

I am not sure what the entity path for my azure message queue is, and don't know how I should look it up?

I initialized my message factory as such;

```
public Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessagingFactory client = Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessagingFactory.CreateFromConnectionString(ServiceBusConnectString);
```

Where servicebusconnectionstring, is the primary conenctionstring extracted from the azure queue, or by following this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-get-started-with-queues#1-create-a-namespace-using-the-azure-portal

The message sender is created as such:

```
Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessageSender sender = client.CreateMessageSender(destinationQueue,queueName);
```

Again destionationQueue, and queueName are strings, which are defined from azure?

The message is to be send is created as such:

```
Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.BrokeredMessage message = new Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.BrokeredMessage(e.ToXml());
```

`e` is just an object, which has publich function which can convert it to an xml string.

Here is where I send the message:

```
try
{
   IntegrationLogger.Write(LogLevel.Verbose, "Sending message to azure");
   sender.Send(message);
}
catch(System.Exception ex)
{
  if(ex is System.TimeoutException)
  {
    IntegrationLogger.Write(LogLevel.Error, "Timeout exeption");
  }

  if (ex is System.ArgumentException)
  {
    IntegrationLogger.Write(LogLevel.Error, "Message is empty");
  }

}
```

`IntegrationLogger` is a log function I use - and the last message being logged is "Sending message to azure", meaning somethng goes wrong when I send it. 
even catch does not catch the exception?..

What could be the problem here?

Am I using the sender incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am not sure what the enity path for my azure message queue is, and don't know how i should look it up?

If we want to create queue [MessageSender](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.messagesender?view=azure-dotnet), we could use following code.

```
var sender = client.CreateMessageSender(queueName);
```

We also could use queueclient to send and  receive the broker messsage.

```
var client = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString("servicebus connection string", queueName);

// how to send message
var sendMessage = new BrokeredMessage(data);
client.Send(sendMessage);

//how to receive message
client.OnMessage(message =>
{
     var dataInfo = message.GetBody<T>();
});
```

> IntegrationLogger is a log function I use - and the last message being logged is "Sending message to azure", meaning somethng goes wrong when I send it. even catch does not catch the exepetion?..

In your case I recommand that you could add the log info to check whether there is any exception during send message.

```
 try
 {
   IntegrationLogger.Write(LogLevel.Verbose, "Sending message to azure");
   sender.Send(message);
   //add log
   IntegrationLogger.Write(LogLevel.Verbose, "Send message successfully"); 
 }
```